# Gatsby redirects

Tags: gatsby-cloud

External sources beyond my control link to pages like: `somedomain.com/Some-Path` which results in a 404 because the path is case sensitive.

I'm getting a "too many redirects" error in production (it works fine local) when using the following:

```
const url = '/*'

createRedirect({
  fromPath: url,
  toPath: url.toLowerCase(),
})
```

For context I'm hosting with Gatsby Cloud and using their plugin `gatsby-plugin-gatsby-cloud`

The expectation is that `somedomain.com/Some-Path` will redirect to `somedomain.com/some-path`

Comment: I ended up just writing a function in the 404 page to check for uppercase and to navigate to the lowercase version. However, getting the above to work would be the preferred method.